# Tried to use DataSourceFactory for setting up datebase in the configuration but import io.dropwizard.db not working which has DataSourceFactory class

Tags: java, maven, dropwizard

I tried using DataSourceFactory class for setting up my database in my dropwizard application.But i am not able to import io.dropwizard.db.DatasourceFactory because .db is not installed as dependency.I have tried updating my POM.xml file and used mvn clean install in intelliJ.But its not working.I am giving my POM.xml file below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
    http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>io.dropwizard</groupId>
<artifactId>dropwizard-core</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>dropwizard_demo2</name>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <dropwizard.version>2.1.1</dropwizard.version>
    <mainClass>dropwizard.dropwizard_demo2Application</mainClass>
</properties>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.dropwizard</groupId>
            <artifactId>dropwizard-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${dropwizard.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.dropwizard</groupId>
        <artifactId>dropwizard-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.validation-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.dropwizard</groupId>
        <artifactId>dropwizard-db</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <createDependencyReducedPom>true</createDependencyReducedPom>
                <transformers>
                    <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer"/>
                    <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                        <mainClass>${mainClass}</mainClass>
                    </transformer>
                </transformers>
                <!-- exclude signed Manifests -->
                <filters>
                    <filter>
                        <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                            <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                            <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                    </filter>
                </filters>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <mainClass>${mainClass}</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.10.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>attach-sources</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>jar</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>attach-javadocs</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>jar</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<reporting>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <dependencyLocationsEnabled>false</dependencyLocationsEnabled>
                <dependencyDetailsEnabled>false</dependencyDetailsEnabled>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.0</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</reporting>
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>java11+</id>
        <activation>
            <jdk>[11,)</jdk>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <!--
            Workaround for "javadoc: error - The code being documented uses modules but the packages
            defined in https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/ are in the unnamed module."
            -->
            <maven.javadoc.skip>true</maven.javadoc.skip>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
</project>
```